# Where can I ask a question about software licensing calculations?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question about software licensing. It's not a technical question. It's a question about formulas used in the industry for pricing licenses. Is there any SE site which would be appropriate for this kind of question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest recommendations would be:

If open-source software:  [OpenSource SE](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/)

Else, [Law SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/)

---

As you say it's a business issue, then [Startups SE](https://startups.stackexchange.com/) would be the place [if post is formatted and structured properly]

Comment: No, it's not opensource. And it's not a legal issue either. It's a business issue.

Comment: @user93353 Edited my answer. :)

Comment: I got the exact same idea which I was reading your answer - and I had already started drafting my question there :-)